# How to loop over excel sheet and lists in Stata?

Tags: excel, foreach, stata

I just started working with Stata and I couldn't figure out the following.

1. How can I loop over the lists of Excel sheets and the indices. This works fine now.

   ```
   clear all
   set more off

   local mysheets 1996 2000 2003 2007 2008 2010 
   local indices index1 index2 index3

   foreach sheetname of local mysheets {

       import excel "C:\stata\Data.xls", sheet(`sheetname') firstrow clear

       foreach index of local indices{
          tobit theta index, ll(0) ul(1)
          outreg using "C:\stata\results.doc" , `append'
          local append "append"    
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: Note that your `local`s are named differently: `mysheets` vs. `mysheet`

Comment: Also, you are using `'append'` before you define it (note the incorrect use of `'`; I can't figure out how to get SO to allow me to use the proper backtick in this context). And it's not clear why you would define it in the first place (in this context, at least).

Comment: @Brendan Thank you. Fixed that and it still not working. As for append I found that in that way if the file is not created already it wouldn't append for the first time but would for the rest.

Comment: Oh I have to change  `sheetname` to ` `sheetname' ` and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to post as an answer (so the question doesn't appear unanswered), since it seems to be a simple coding error:

- Make sure local macro names are consistent throughout (`mysheet` vs. `mysheets`)
- Use local macro syntax for the argument of `foreach` (in this case, `sheetname`) inside of `foreach` loop
- If using a local macro to define the `append` option of `outreg`, define it before the option is called

  ```
  clear all
  set more off
  local mysheets 1996 2000 2003 2007 2008 2010 
  local indices index1 index2 index3

  foreach sheetname of local mysheets {
      import excel "C:\stata\Data.xls", sheet(`sheetname') firstrow clear
      foreach index of local indices {
         tobit theta `index', ll(0) ul(1)
         local append "append"    
         outreg using "C:\stata\results.doc" , `append'
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Might I add also Brendan to add the ticks on the index macro variable within the nested foreach loop: `tobit theta ` ` `index', ll(0) ul(1)`

Comment: Thanks; was only correcting the items previously identified, but you are of course correct.